# Dealing with whitespace in scanf and printf

Tags: c

I'm trying to come up with a C program that can accept whitespace in `scanf` and `printf` such as a first and last name, as part of a self-learning text I'm reading.

I'm well-aware of buffer overflow potentiality and such security issues with these basic/old functions, but this is strictly for learning purposes, so I do need to stick to them.

My program looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[30];

    printf("Type your name\n");

    scanf("%10[0-9a-zA-Z]", name);

    printf("%s\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

and after compilation is able to read in the string with a whitespace, but I can only print the first chunk of text:

```
C:\Users\hackr>g++ -o whitespace.exe whitespace.c

C:\Users\hackr>whitespace.exe
Type your name
John Doe
John

C:\Users\hackr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scanf("%29[0-9a-zA-Z ]", name);
                    ^
```

You forgot to add a space to the accepted characters in your regex. Also, if your buffer is 30 bytes, you should accept 29 characters, not 10. Leave room for the NUL character.

Another thing to note is that the next time you read from `stdin`, it will read the characters in that line that weren't within the first 29 characters of that `scanf` before it begins reading the input from the next prompt. In order to fix that, add this after the `scanf`:

```
while (getchar() != '\n')
    ; // read input to end of line
```

This will always work since `'\n'` is not in your accepted characters for the regex so it will be left in the `stdin` buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
scanf("%29[^\n]", name);
```

This will read till a newline is encountered.

Comment: That works too! That's probably a better way of doing it since it's simpler. Thanks

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]", name);` will scan nothing into `name`, leaving it uninitialized if the first key is <Enter>.

Comment: I'm going to have to flip a coin on which of the 2 solutions to mark as accepted because they're both very good answers and they were written at the same time.

Comment: @Hack-R If you'd rather go with this option, use ``scanf("%29[^\n]", name);`` so you can avoid a buffer overflow.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts , yes, don't know why I didn't think of that before. Thanks